# Solving for pressure in NS equation

Tags: analysis, partial-differential-equations, regularity-theory-of-pdes, linear-pde

Let us consider the Navier-Stokes equation in $\mathbb{R}^3$ subjected to no gravitational forces provided by the formula:

\begin{align}
\dfrac{\partial }{\partial t} \textbf{u} + \left(\textbf{u}\cdot \nabla \right)\textbf{u} &= \nu \nabla^{2} \textbf{u}-\dfrac{1}{\rho}  \nabla p \\
\nabla \cdot \textbf{u} &= 0 \\
\textbf{u}(x,0) &= \textbf{u}^0(x)
\end{align}

Here $\rho>0$ is a scalar which represents the fluids density and $\nu>0$ is a scalar which denotes the fluids kinetic viscosity. If We compute the divergence of the first equation we find

\begin{equation}
\nabla \cdot \biggl[\left(\textbf{u}\cdot \nabla \right)\textbf{u} - \nu \nabla^{2} \textbf{u}\biggr] =  -\dfrac{1}{\rho} \nabla^2 p
\end{equation}

here $\nabla^2$ is the Laplacian operator. So the diffusion of pressure is the divergence of this non-linear vector field. Whenever the Laplacian operator has an inverse, say $(\square)^{-1}$ for simplicity), one can apply this function to obtain

$$(\square)^{-1} \biggl(\nabla \cdot -\rho \biggl[\left(\textbf{u}\cdot \nabla \right)\textbf{u} - \nu \nabla^{2} \textbf{u}\biggr]\biggr) =  p.$$ This is a mapping which is completely determined by the velocity. Subsituting this into the original equation one then finds

\begin{equation}
 \dfrac{\partial }{\partial t} \textbf{u} + \left(\textbf{u}\cdot \nabla \right)\textbf{u} =    \nu \nabla^{2} \textbf{u}+ (\square)^{-1} \biggl(\nabla \cdot \biggl[\left(\textbf{u}\cdot \nabla \right)\textbf{u} - \nu \nabla^{2} \textbf{u}\biggr]\biggr)
\end{equation}

This is really the inverse Laplacian applied to the divergence of non-linear term. So it is the opposite of the diffusion the divergence of linear term. Any approach to continue this or how you could study the behavior of such a velocity field in this condition

Comment: Terence Tao uses this form to construct some weak solutions among other things in his course on incompressible fluid mechanics https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2018/10/02/254a-notes-2-weak-solutions-of-the-navier-stokes-equations/